# Fading out an article and dropping down a form at the same time?

Tags: jquery

I have an article:

```
<article>
    Some paragraphs.
</article>
```

Below that I have my `contact`:

```
<div id="contact">
    stuff, this form is 600 px tall
</div>
```

`contact` is set to `display:none;`.

I use jQuery to toggle it. What I'm trying to do is modify this script from `http://tutsplus.com/lesson/slides-and-structure/` so that it fades out the article text and then slides in the contact form. Having some trouble.

Code:

```
<script>

(function() {

$('html').addClass('js');

var contactForm = {

    container: $('#contact'),
    article: $('article'),

    init: function() {
        $('<button></button>', {
            text: 'Contact Me'
        })
            .insertAfter('article:first')
            .on('click', function() {
                console.log(this);
                this.show();
                // contactForm.article.fadeToggle(300);
                // contactForm.container.show();
            })
    },

    show: function() {
        contactForm.close.call(contactForm.container);
        contactForm.container.slideToggle(300);
    },

    close: function() {
        console.log(this);
        $('<span class=close>X</span>')
            .prependTo(this)
            .on('click', function(){
                contactForm.article.fadeToggle(300);
                contactForm.container.slideToggle(300);
            })
    }
};

contactForm.init();

})();

</script>
```

The part that is not working is:

```
.on('click', function() {
    console.log(this);
    this.show();
    // contactForm.article.fadeToggle(300);
    // contactForm.container.show();
})
```

When I do `.on('click', this.show);` it works fine, when I put `this.show` in a function it does not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.show()` works just fine within `close()`, because `this` is within scope of `close()`, but not available within scope of `.on('click') callback function`, so you need to keep reference of `this` like below and reuse that.

```
 close: function() {
        // keeping reference
        var reference = this;

        $('<span class=close>X</span>')
            .prependTo(this)
            .on('click', function(){
                //  using above reference here
                reference.article.fadeToggle(300);
                reference.container.slideToggle(300);
            })
    }
```

Comment: In my button in the `init` method, when I click on it I want the article to fade out along with the button and the contact form to fade in. When I click the `X` at the top of the contact form, the contact form fades out and the article along with the button fade in. Thanks for your example, it did help clear up scope for me.

Comment: @eveo glad to help, If any answer helps, you should accept that